# Laravel 5.1 Route::controller with optional url params?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in routes

```
Route::controller('/orders/{from}/{to}', 'CartController');
```

the link something like this

`localhost/admin/orders/2020-01-01/2020-01-02`

this will open all the records between 2 dates

But I have another link something like this

`localhost/admin/orders/4212`

to open specific row on a new tab

This 2 links falls for 1 function

called it

```
 public function getIndex($from,$to){


 }
```

can  I do this params optional? with 1 `Route::controller('/orders/{from}/{to}', 'CartController');` in my route.php?

Comment: Show us the two routes pls... I think I have a solution

Answer (score 2):

You can set any of your parameters to be optional, just by appending `?` at the end of the parameter name. Simple example:

```
Route::controller('/orders/{from?}/{to?}', 'CartController');
```

Also, I jut noticed that you don't call any of your controller actions in your route definition. If you want this route to lead to your getIndex() method, change it to this:

```
Route::controller('/orders/{from?}/{to?}', 'CartController@getIndex');
```

Read more on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::controller('/orders/{from?}/{to?}', 'CartController');
```

```
public function getIndex($from = false,$to = false){


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this like

```
Route::controller('/orders/{from}/{to?}', 'CartController');
```

And in your controller

```
public function getIndex($from,$to=null){
    if($to==null){
        //to open specific row on a new tab
    }
    else{
        // Other task
    }

}
```